# How to use a tileset Id of Mapbox in a layer inside mapboxgl?

Tags: layer, mapbox-gl-js

I have a tileset in my mapbox studio with its correspondent tilesetID.
Is there a way to use this tileset as a layer inside mapboxgl, I mean in a map.addLayer situation?